# The interviewer wants to know if I would jump for a first choice offer if I took this offer

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, careers, hiring

Having told the interviewer I am awaiting news and a potential offer from my first choice, I was asked "when can you start" and after replying, they followed up with "if we offer you this role to you and you took it up only to receive news of an offer from your first choice, would you take it?"

I answered, "I would not on two front. First, it is a matter of principle that I do not go back on my word. Second, it is unprofessional of me to do so."

What motivates this question?

Comment: Is your question actually how you should answer it? Because the question seems pretty transparent - they want to know whether they can trust that you wouldn't be out the door at the first opportunity that comes along (or maybe whether you'd accept but be somewhat unmotivated in the job, given that it's not your first choice).

Answer (score 9):

> What motivates this question?

In this case, the second company knows about your first choice company.  They are trying to gauge the likelihood of you sticking with them should your first choice come back after you have accepted an offer with them.

In other words, they are trying to gauge *how strong your commitment would* be if you took their offer, **knowing** they are not your first choice.  I don't think this is a negative thing for them to ask at all, since you have stated that you have a first choice and the hiring process is expensive.

Comment: Let's continue this discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73202/discussion-on-answer-by-mister-positive-the-interviewer-wants-to-know-if-i-would).